# Free time-tracking app

Tags: gratis, project-management, time-management

Are there any web-apps that allow time-tracking without having to pay for it?

I'm thinking something like Freshbooks, but purely just time tracking based on different projects / tasks.

I know there are a lot of apps out there that claim to be free, but I often find that once I've taken the time to sign up I then find out that isn't the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been happily using [Toggl Track](https://toggl.com/track/), currently [free for up to 5 users](https://toggl.com/track/pricing/), since 2018 on the web and iOS. It lets me track my time spent against [different projects and tasks](https://toggl.com/track/features/).

I have also found it useful to [report on tracked time](https://toggl.com/track/online-time-reporting/), e.g. for tracking my hours worked from home for tax purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check out ActivityWatch which is open-source and cross-platform. The features below are taken from their website (https://activitywatch.net/):

- Tracking: Tracks active application and window title out of the box, more with watchers.
- Categories: Get a better overview of your usage by breaking it down
  into categories.
- Browser extensions: Track the active tab using the extensions for Chrome and Firefox.
- Editor plugins: Track how you spend time writing code with editor watchers.
- Privacy: Data is stored locally and doesn't leave your device, we put local and privacy first.
- Cross-platform: Runs on Windows, macOS, Linux, and Android.
- Synchronization: Sync your activity between your devices. (We're working on it)

Most of the time I spend on my computer is online. Monitoring the active tab is very important to me, but it also raises some privacy concerns. On the other hand, this is an inherent problem for all trackers. At least, ActivityWatch is open source.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Kimai](https://www.kimai.org/):

- It is multi-user, open-source, and can be self-hosted. This is the free version.
- It has an easy screen to enter all weekly work in one go, if required. Hence can be used for "5 working days" entry.
- It has reports for summary of working hours per week/month/year etc.
- It has a timer for those that want to time tasks/acvtivities.
- It works well on a mobile client too. I believe there is also now an android app.